# Can I add or remove design variables from a problem after setup() call?

Tags: openmdao

I have a mixed-integer optimization problem that I am trying to solve. I've been trying to solve the problem with penalty methods with little success and am wanting to try some alternative methods. From what I can tell, some options are AMIEGO, a GA, and a branch and bound (BNB) type solver. I'm particularly interested in a BNB approach, but I don't see a branch and bound driver or solver in OpenMDAO (https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/building_blocks/drivers/index.html?highlight=drivers). However a basic implementation is relatively straightforward to write. From what I've tested, the BNB algorithm starts with solving a relaxed problem to which constraints are added for subsequent solves until the problem converges to an integer solution.

My issue is that I need to call `setup()` every time I need to add a new constraint to the problem. Normally this would be okay, but the setup process for my problem is quite long. Is it possible to add constraints or design variables to a problem after `setup()` has been called. In the documentation, I see that there are related function `configure()` and `final_setup()`, which may be useful? However, to be honest I don't completely understand their utility. Or is their any other way in which you would recommend I approach the developing the BNB driver?

I hope this makes sense and thanks in advance for any advice you offer.

Comment: If you are keen on OpenMDAO, then maybe the problem at hand is "how can I make incremental setup() less expensive?" That is, given a problem P, and related problem P' which has one additional constraint, how could we minimize the amount of stuff that needs to be re-computed from scratch? But you [showed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) us no code, so it's not clear what could be cached or cheaply derived.

Comment: Its hard to guess why your setup is so expensive, but thats not a super common occurrence. I gave a very general answer, but if you can provide a code sample showing the structure of you model and why its so expensive I may be able to give a more concrete answer.

Comment: I'll follow up with code if the suggestions you provided don't work well. The model is quite large (10-15 components) so I don't know exactly what would be useful to show....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setup` process is top-down. The `configure` process is bottom-up. The main use-case for `configure` is for situations where parent groups need to get some information from their children before finishing the configuration of their I/O or connections. `configure` happens after the whole model hierarchy is complete and hence you are sure that any layer of tree below yourself is complete and already fully configured.

`final_setup` is the very last step in the process, where OpenMDAO knows that all the I/O and connections are fully done. So it can do the memory allocation it needs to make the model work.

Users don't normally need to call `final_setup` themselves, as OpenMDAO will call it right before it needs to actually do any work. There are a few corner use cases where folks have found it helpful to get the memory fully allocated before they call `run_model` or `run_driver` --- so we made the method public.

However, none of these methods seem to be exactly the solution to your problem. I am a bit surprised to hear that your setup-process is expensive. The work OpenMDAO does during setup is not terribly computationally heavy and we don't typically see huge setup costs. There are a few times where I've seen it get costly though. These are cases with hundreds or thousands of individual components and variables. (Models with many many instances of a [pyCycle](https://github.com/openmdao/pycycle) model are one example where that can happen). The cost of setup does scale with the number of components/groups/variables. So if you have high setup cost, perhaps you have a model like this.

If that is the case, we typically work around this challenge by using [sub-problems](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/RevHack2020/blob/master/solution_approaches/sub_problems.md). For a top level model that had many copies of a pyCycle thermodynamic model in it, we would take the pyCycle model group and stick that into a sub-problem inside a component. By limiting the overall depth of the model higherachy, substantial savings can be found. I've seen this drop setup times from minutes to under a second.

Or perhaps you have some other non-openmdao calculations that are done once in `setup()` and that you don't want to have to repeat. In that case, I might consider moving those calculations into some kind of a pre-run step that you can do outside of OpenMDAO's setup and just re-use.

One final option, if you really really can't find a way to make setup costs more affordable would be to make use of the feature that lets you change DV and constraint bounds after setup. Here, the actual DVs and constraints themselves (i.e. the variables they point to) need to be created all at setup time. But you could create bounds that effectively locked them in place (set the upper and lower bounds to the same value) when you needed to constrain things further. [This feature is in OpenMDAO as over version 3.23](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.23.0/features/core_features/adding_desvars_cons_objs/modifying_desvars_cons_obj.html?highlight=set_design_var_options) --- it was proposed in [POEM 72](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/POEMs/pull/149/files). I will say that I think this method is likely to be somewhat tricky. If you're just bounding design variables then it will probably work fine. However, over-constraining problems with very tight bounds on outputs is a bit more numerically challenging. You're effectively creating an equality constraint, without telling the optimizer that you're doing it. You might have better luck by allowing some small delta between the upper and lower bounds of the output constraints.

Overall, I recommend you find a way to speed up your setup call, either with sub-problems or by moving the expensive calcs out of OpenMDAO's setup stack and doing them only once (maybe some kind of top level configuration object you could pass into your model as an option). If you can't do that, maybe you can add all the constraints/dvs ahead of time and manage their activation via the changing the bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. That is quite helpful. I'm actually somewhat familiar with the sub problem approach, but did not consider using it in this instance. I'll have to come back to that if these other approaches do not work. My problem is a dymos problem, so I think it may actually be quite large, but I'll double check my component setup methods and time them anyways. I do have some one-time computations in there, but I thought they were relatively benign.

Comment: That feature in OpenMDAO v3.23 is pretty much exactly what I'm looking for (I couldn't find that detail in the docs to thanks!). However, I don't quite understand the statement "You're effectively creating an equality constraint, without telling the optimizer that you're doing it". Are you saying that the solver will interpret `lower=1,upper=1` and `equals=1` differently? In that case I should do `lower=1-epsilon,upper=1+epsilon`...

Comment: Something I just noticed is that `set_design_var_options` and `set_constraint_options` does not appear to work if the `indices=[]` argument was used in the original `add_design_var` and `add_constraint` call... Looks like I'll need to cleanup() my setup functions.

Comment: that sounds like a bug. I've reported it here: https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/issues/2775

Comment: I wanted to follow up after some additional debugging based on your suggestions and it looks like my `setup()` functions are not the issue. Currently my call to `prob.setup()` is about 7.0s on average. From what I've figured out ~0.1s is calling the `setup()` functions. An overwhelming majority of the setup time (~6.5s) is spent in `._configure()` in group.py. Specifically, the issue is the `configure()` in phase.py when `transcription.configure_timeseries_outputs(self)` is called. There is another slight slowdown in the Trajectory configure function call (est. 0.2s).

Comment: Also, I'm in dymos 1.2.0 and openmdao 3.16.0. I've tried updating to newer versions, but my problem runs significantly slower in the newer versions for whatever reason. Is there any additional information I can provide that could better help you figure out what exactly is going on here? Also, if it's the dymos configure functions that are giving me issues, I don't know if the problem wrapping component will necessarily work right? Maybe if I wrap the entire dymos problem?

Comment: without some kind of working example code, its hard to give any more specific support. I've not seen a dymos configure method be a bottleneck before, but that almost certainly means that you have ALOT of different variables that you are integrating. Did you create a large number of scalar variables? If so, try concatenating them into an array instead.

Comment: If you can share your model, you might try submitting an issue directly to the Dymos repo. Im sure they'd like to see the case you've built up that is exposing some kind of bottleneck.

Comment: I don't have many scalar variables. Almost everything is either a matrix or vector. But I do have a relatively large number of variables in the dymos problem. I think I should be able to share my code. Should I just put everything into a .zip file and just upload it to the Dymos repo?

Comment: open an issue on dymos. If you have a bunch of files, maybe make a public repo with them and link to it in the dymos issue.

Comment: Can do. I'll try to get to it shortly.